# Make Springboot @service class method access by only one thread at a time

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, autowired

I need to make my @service class a method can be access only one thread at a time. I can't add `static synchronized` keywords to the method due to that method call `@Autowired` another instances.

Please advice on this.

Thank you.

Added sample java class here,

```
@Service
public class Saver implements DataSaver {

    @Autowired
    private SaverLogic saverLogic;
    
    
    @Override
    public String process(...) {
        Future<String> result = saverLogic.save(repositoryContainer, entities);

    }
```

I need to make process() method `static synchronized` but due to autowired instance I can't do this. SaverLogic class contains a `@Async` method.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Why would it need to be static? And why wouldn't you be able to add `syncronized`? Also adding that is probably a bad idea anyway. Why do you need single thread access in the first place... As that will severly impact (cripple in this case) your performance.

Comment: @Autowired private RateLogic rateLogic; I have this autowired class in this service class and inside the method call this instance. If I make this method as static then there is a error. I can add synchronized but I need to add both static synchronized because I need to make this method can access only one thread

Comment: I need to make this method can access only one thread due to I have to serve according to requests coming order. Thank you for your reply above, please help me on this.

Comment: You really don't want it syncronized. Also I don't get it why it sould be `static` in the first place... I suspect you have a total misunderstand of what `static` actually is and what `syncronized` is. Nonetheless making it `syncronized` is going to be very bad for your performance.

Comment: This is my understand, please correct if I'm wrong. Also I have added sample code to the above.
adding synchronized keyword to the method then it one instance will access only one thread. Adding to the static to that then it will become class level and that method only access one thread without considering instance. is this correct? I saw that actually when I send multiple requests to the controller same time but its process one by one before adding the autowired things. After adding autowired I'm getting error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field rateSaverLogic". Thank you

Comment: You cannot use autowired instances in class level methods. As those don't operate on instances but on the class level in the first place. Still it isn't clear why you would need syncronized... The `@Async` has nothing to do with `syncronized`. Looks like you should solve the issue preventing you from doing concurrent access instead of limiting access (unless you want to cripple your application). Another option is to use a class level lock and obtain/release it to have single access, but all of the solutions feel like a workaround for another issue you should actually be solving.

Comment: Actually I need to do like this. I have a consumer project and controller get different type of data. For a one type (Rate) I need to save data one by one. If multiple requests going to save the data same time its getting a problem. So I have added synchronized static key word to the method. Due to the data size I have added @Async data saving due to some "socket close" error. Hope you got an idea, Thank you.

Comment: No I still don't and imho you are still solving the wrong problem. As stated you cannot use `static` here and when using `syncronized` it will work for the instance itself. Even using `static syncronized` isn't foolproof what if you scale up to multiple instances of the application? So you are solving the wrong problem.